# Batch script - Record every restart in .txt file

Tags: windows-xp

I don't have expiriance in batch scripting bat I need help.
i need a script that will do the following:
After every windows restart, this action must be writen in one .txt file (eg. 'log_restart.txt'). 
My company want to know number of restarts per every computer, and they want to have recorded it in one file. 
Which is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI to query the system log for the shutdown and restart event.  There could be other parts of WMI thats has this info too.  Use the WMI Code Creator to generate your code.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572

- Class: Win32_NTLogEvent
- Logfile: System

You can look over the event log with event viewer to figure out what events you want to record.  Set the script to run on startup and it will write them to the file for you, recording the events.  Personally, I think you should just setup a real monitoring system that will record these events to a central log.  Look at syslog.

UPDATE:  There is a setting that hold the last boot time...

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_OperatingSystem instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "LastBootUpTime: " & objItem.LastBootUpTime
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have generated the code and I saved it as a .vb script and put in startup. And I don't know what next? How and where I can see the log file?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how to use VBScript.  The most basic programming classes teach you how to write text files.  This is not a place for people to do your work.  Its a place for people to help guide you to the water.  If you dont know how to drink, you must learn on your own.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I success. I do not use VBScript, I use web oriented languages such as php, ruby, python etc, but I have no expirience with MS administration and languages and because I needed your help.In any case Thank you.